# Separate hashtags and text PHP

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace, hashtag

[image: My database]

Hi this is an example of my table, I want to be able to search like this: #mat#godis and be able to get the 2 results having those tags (ID 5 and ID 7)

This i my PHP code so far and it works while searching for example (Globen), (Globen #mat) and (#mat)

```
//Strip Search
function selectSearch($search){
$lol = preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/'," ",$search);
$keywords = explode(" ", preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $lol));
foreach($keywords as $keyword){
 $wherelike[] = "name LIKE '%$keyword%'";
}
$search = implode(" and ", $wherelike);
return $search;
}

//Strip tags
function selectTags($tags){
$str = $tags;
    $bits = explode(' ', $str);
    $newquery = array();

    foreach($bits as $bit){
        if(strlen($bit) > 0 && $bit[0] === '#') $newquery[] = $bit;
    }

    $newquery = implode('', $newquery);

    $keywords = explode(" ", preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $newquery));
    foreach($keywords as $keyword){
        $wherelike[] = "tags LIKE '%".ltrim($keyword,'#')."%'";
    }
    $tags = implode(" or ", $wherelike);    

    return $tags;
}
```

It returns (searching for #mat#godis)

```
select * from stores where name LIKE '%%' and name LIKE '%#godis%' and tags LIKE '%mat#godis%'order by id desc limit 8
```

I want the query to be something like this

```
select * from stores where name LIKE '%%'and tags LIKE '%mat%' and tags LIKE '%godis%' order by id desc limit 8
```

Comment: How set-in-stone is your database design? I would change that, frankly, to add a store_tag relation.

Comment: Can you tell us how `$tag` looks like?

Answer (score 2):

This design is really bad. You need to use a relation table. The problem is, if you try to search `%#mat%`, then, if there is a tag like `#matheus`, that will also give you result.

Of course, there are workaround for this situation, but that is too complicated.

And i do not understand what is this:  `name LIKE '%%'`

So what you need is to create table, as ChrisForrence mentioned, called `store_tag` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store_tag` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tag like #mat',
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The foreign ID',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

After this, you need to write a little script, what is loop thorugh on all the records in your original table, get out the id and the tags, explodes the tags, insert it individually in your new table `store_tag`.

And then, use:

`SELECT * FROM store_tag, orig_table INNER JOIN origTable ON origTable.id = store_tag.user_id  WHERE tag = '#mat' OR tag = '#godis'`

(The query above is not tested, this is just for example, and of course you do not need to `SELECT *`).

This will give you back the desired results.

It's much more easier to maintain your data.

Of course befor this creat a backup from your existing database.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, I would create a separate table for tags, like such:

```
# The original table. Notice the lack of a 'tags' column
CREATE TABLE `stores` (
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

# A new table, relating stores to tags
CREATE TABLE `store_tags` (
  `store_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  `label` VARCHAR(64),
  PRIMARY KEY(`store_id`, `label`),
  FOREIGN KEY(`store_id`) REFERENCES `stores`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

From here, you can use a variation of the following query to check for stores matching all of the tags:

```
SELECT * FROM `stores` 
    WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `store_id` FROM `store_tags` WHERE `label`='mat') 
      AND `id` IN (SELECT `store_id` FROM `store_tags` WHERE `label`='godis')
    ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 8
```

You can use this to split the tags out into the proper WHERE clause, along with an array of tags used as input parameters for your PDO query

```
/* Returns an array containing the WHERE clauses, along 
 * with the tags themselves (used to populate the input parameters for PDO)
 */
function searchTags($in) {
  $rQ = '';

  // Filter out empty array input elements
  $tags = array_filter(explode('#', $in));
  if(!count($tags)) {
    return false;
  }

  $first = true;
  foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $rQ .= ($first ? ' WHERE' : ' AND') . ' `id` IN (SELECT `store_id` FROM `store_tags` WHERE `label`=?)';
    if($first) $first = false;
  }
  return array($rQ, $tags);

}
```